# go get vs go install on go.sum file

Tags: go

I'm using go 1.20.3

I've just install this packages with go get and go install

```
go get -v github.com/mactsouk/go/simpleGitHub
go install  github.com/mactsouk/go/simpleGitHub
```

what i have on my go.sum file is:

```
github.com/mactsouk/go v0.0.0-20180603081621-6a282087f7bd h1:TqJGx/jAxlJ3RNL7pS7XZQlvtH8rL/dUsA8wPe9W4y0=
github.com/mactsouk/go v0.0.0-20180603081621-6a282087f7bd/go.mod h1:TRtlPc1xi1zOQdbA/cIxGdS+fCaIZDQUpMrFlET5dbI=
```

and on the go.mod file is:

```
module calculator

go 1.20

require github.com/mactsouk/go v0.0.0-20180603081621-6a282087f7bd // indirect
```

aod on my $Home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mactsouk/

```
dr-xr-xr-x  5 user  staff  160 Jul  4 18:42 go@v0.0.0-20180603081621-6a282087f7bd
```

and nothing on $Home/go/bin/ but two files, why go install did not copied binary files for simpleGitHub module ?

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 user  staff       128 Jun 26 23:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 user  staff       128 Jun 26 23:35 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff   3410064 Jun 26 23:35 go-outline
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  28237216 Jun 26 23:37 gopls
```

there are differences between go get and go install ? why i have on go.sum files this module twice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go get vs go install

The ***go get*** and ***go install*** commands in Go serve different purposes:

***go get*** is used to retrieve and download packages and their dependencies from remote repositories. It updates the go.mod and go.sum files with the versions of the downloaded packages. If the package is already present, go get will update it to the latest version.

***go install*** compiles and installs the package in your project's *GOPATH* or *GOBIN*. It does not update the go.mod or go.sum files. Instead, it uses the information in those files to determine the correct versions of the dependencies to use.

In your case, when you ran go get, it downloaded and installed the package github.com/mactsouk/go/simpleGitHub and its dependencies. This action updated the go.mod and go.sum files with the versions of the downloaded packages.

When you subsequently ran go install for the same package, it didn't need to download the package again because it was already present in your local Go module cache. Therefore, go install used the existing package and its version from the cache, and it didn't modify the go.mod or go.sum files.

The reason you see the module listed twice in the go.sum file is because it contains both the module version *(v0.0.0-20180603081621-6a282087f7bd)* and its corresponding go.mod file with a checksum. This is the expected behavior and ensures the integrity of the dependencies.

To summarize, go get and go install have different purposes, and the duplication of the module in the go.sum file is normal.

Comment: thanks, but , why go install did not copied binary files for simpleGitHub module on my home/bin? see my question updated

Comment: @DDave, What directory does `go env GOBIN` report? Do you find the expected binaries from `go install` in that directory?

Comment: i've installed go with brew,on a mac, the gobin is empty: GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""

Comment: @DDave, In that case it should be installing the binaries in `$(go env GOPATH)/bin`. I know you checked `$HOME/go/bin` but double-check that `GOPATH` is `$HOME/go` and not some other directory.

Comment: @DDave, I ran `go install  github.com/mactsouk/go/simpleGitHub@latest` and got the error `package github.com/mactsouk/go/simpleGitHub is not a main package`. Looking at the project the only file is named *simpleGithub.go* and begins with `package simpleGitHub`. So, of course, `go install` will fail and not create a binary. Where did you get the idea it would install a binary?